# Creating a custom view to replace UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've had a lot of experience customizing UINavigationBars and find it is a royal pain in the a** to get it to do what I want without a lot of effort. So I've written my own custom UIView that behaves just like a UINavigationBar and is fully and easily customizable. However, I am having a problem, when the Navigation controller pushes a new controller onto the stack, my custom view stops receiving touch events.

To make this more clear, my app loads and displays a view controller, in the viewDidLoad method, I create and add my custom nav bar to the controller's view. A navigation controller is created programmatically and a view controller is pushed to it.  At this point my custom view is on top and receiving touch events.  When I push another view controller to the navigation controller's stack, my custom view is still on top and visible, but not receiving events.

So my question is how to I get my custom nav bar back into the responder chain?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to support iOS < 5.0 you should try to add the UINavigationBar using UINavigationController's `- (instancetype)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass` method instead of doing it manually.

Comment: That's interesting... Hadn't noticed this method before... Unfortunately, for this project, I need to support back to 4.3... But thanks anyway.

Comment: Is anyone still using 4.3? :)

Comment: Probably not, but my client wants to make sure that anyone can use the app so he wants to go back as far as possible...  My opinion is, if someone is still using 4.3, you probably don't want them as a customer anyway...